Node module compiled against different node version error when extending an existing electron app
I am extending an existing electron app.  I have started a framework using the documentation here:
https://www.electronjs.org/fr/docs/latest/tutorial/Construire%20votre%20Premi%C3%A8re%20App
I then copied the resources (contents of the app folder) sans package.json (don't overwrite the new package.json) from the existing app into the new app folder I created (electronapp), then started the app.  I get the following error:
App threw an error during load
Error: The module '/Users/xxx/xxx/electronapp/binding.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 130. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

I tried running npm rebuild and npm install but I still get the same error.  I tried removing binding.node and running those commands again to see if it would generate a new one, but then I get a "file not found" error.  I also tried npm rebuild binding.node.
Based on this page:
Electron App was compiled against a different Node.js version Error
I installed electron-rebuild and ran it, still get error.
Based on this page:
Serialport module compiled against different node version
I installed electron-builder, added script to devDependencies, and ran the script.  Then I launched the newly built app in the dist/mac/ folder, but get popup with the same error.
I also looked at several other resources which proved unfruitful.
I observe that binding.node was not in my initial framework, but was copied over from the app I am extending.
Running navigator.userAgent in the console of the app I am extending reveals it is built on electron version 6.1.12 .
How do I rebuild the binding.node file?  There is another file, ffi_bindings.node which I suspect may give me trouble also.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "reolink_8.8.2_ext",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Reolink Client Extended Version",
  "main": "background.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "author": "Kevin Jones",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^33.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^25.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.9"
  }
}

System: Macos
